# how to use google polymer ui component in nodejs express app

Tags: node.js, express, polymer

I am working on nodejs express app. I want to include google polymer ui components in my express app.I tried a lot about integrating polymer in express app. I found no solution for this.  **Is there any way to integrate polymer ui component in express app ?**

Answer (score 0):

I used polymer webcomponents to create a node express server found on this: [express-web-components](https://github.com/scramjs/express-web-components)

His tutorial shows how to use webcomponents to create a server, but you can clearly adopt that to your usecase and use ui components like the server ones. Note: To use the server-side web components, the [ScramEngine](https://github.com/scramjs/scram-engine) offers access to the runtime.

Basically it is:

1. Include polymer and your component like so:

`<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/express-web-components/express-app.html">`

2. Use your component for example like so.

`<express-app port="1234">
    <express-middleware>
    </express-middleware>
</express-app>`

*This is only for Polymer 2. Version 3 will be different from the import side.*